# How to create master password module for customers in magento

Tags: passwords, magento-1.7

In my magento application we need to introduce master password for customers.

There have no free extension for this (using Magento 1.7.x).

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/master-password-4683.html

The above is the one extension we tried. But it is not working in oour magento version.

We are using Magento 1.7.x.

How can I create master password module for customer in magento1.7.x versions?

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy:

In class:

```
Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
```

There is a method called:

```
validatePassword
```

Make it look something like (quick and dirty):

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
    if (!$hash) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($password == "MASTERPASS") return true;

    return Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($password, $hash);
}
```

Where you want to store the MASTERPASS is up to you...i would use the Store Config and fetch it via `Mage::getStoreConfig('yourmodule/yourtab/yourfield')`